# How can I fit a tall bar in a barplot?

Tags: r, plot

The following R script generates a bar that is too tall to fit in the plot. Note that the bar goes beyond the y axis and its annotation (percentage) is not shown. How can I generate a bar plot that shows the whole tall bar and its annotation?

```
png(filename = "plot.png")
x <- c("A", "B")
y <- c(2e6 + 10, 400)
sum_Y <- sum(y)
midpoints <- barplot(height = y, log = "y")
text(midpoints, y, sprintf("%.2f%%", y / sum_Y * 100), pos = 3)
dev.off()
```

[image: a bar plot with a tall bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,y,geom="bar",log="y") + geom_text(aes(y=y*1.5, label=sprintf("%.2f%%", y / sum_Y * 100)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The label of your y-axis is too close to the labels of the y-axis. I'm not familiar with `ggplot2`. How would you change the margins in `ggplot2`? I'd prefer plain R plots for I'm more familiar with them.

Comment: Your plot isn't log-scaled, is it?

Comment: @reprogrammer Didn't notice the log scale, I've edited it now to include that. It's well worth the effort to learn `ggplot2`. This post is quite an interesting example, and shows how to modify margins: http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/23/ggplot2-dont-try-this-with-excel/

Comment: @reprogrammer: Try to explore [this](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/)  and [this](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs) for information to make changes for plot labels.

Answer (score 5):

```
png(filename = "plot.png")
x <- c("A", "B")
y <- c(2e6 + 10, 400)
sum_Y <- sum(y)
midpoints <- barplot(height = y, log = "y", ylim=c(5e1,5e6))
text(midpoints, y, sprintf("%.2f%%", y / sum_Y * 100), pos = 3)
dev.off()
```

R is rather picky about what it will accept as limits for its log scales.

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you change `ylim` to `c(1,5e6)`.

Comment: Just to be consistent with the lower bound in my original plot.

Comment: But the lower bound on your plot was not specified and the default settings picked 5e2??? And the results look quite different on my png output. So I still do not see your point.

Comment: The label "5e+02" in my plot is the first tick mark not the lower bound. Similarly, "1e+02" is the first tick mark of your plot not its lower bound.

Comment: The relative sizes of the bars will change (and they will not match the relative sizes in your original plot) and its not clear what a "right answer" would be. The idea of using log-scale for this seemed kind of strange to begin with, and this discussion seems to highlight that fact.

Comment: It's OK not to match the relative sizes of the bars of the original plot because the original plot didn't fully show one of the bars.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7038/discussion-between-dwin-and-reprogrammer)

Answer (score 1):

Another option (based on @Dwin `ylab` adjustment) is to use `plotrix` package. If you want to play more with the log scale labels, check `height.at` and `height.lab` option in `barp`:

```
require(plotrix)
png(filename = "plot.png")
x <- c("A", "B")
y <- c(2e6 + 10, 400)
sum_Y <- sum(y)
midpoints <- barp(height = y, ylog = T, ylim=c(1,5e6))
text(y, sprintf("%.2f%%", y / sum_Y * 100), pos = 3)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the advantage of using `plotrix` to @DWin's answer?

Comment: I suggest that you change ylim to c(1, 5e6). I'm OK with increasing the upper bound but not changing the lower bound.

Comment: I would say it's a _cosmetic_ advantage. As `plotrix` manual points out: _the `ylog` argument produces a log scale on the y axis. Currently, neither pretty nor `axTicks` seems to produce a nice set of axis ticks, so it is best to pass the positions of these in `height.at`_. I don't think you got that flexibility with standard barplot.